# Is there any way to Signout the user from dropbox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox Chooser API for accessing it's contents. I need to provide a SignOut option in my application which should make Signoff the user from Dropbox. Rather than redirecting to dropbox account and choosing the Signout option, I need to add a button in my application which should either Signout from Dropbox or redirecting to Dropbox Signoff page. So is there any way to do it using Javascript?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, there's no programmatic way to log a user out of Dropbox. Why do you need to do this? (In general, we don't want developers forcing a user to log out. That should be something only the user does.)

Comment: here's a use case. A user on a public computer interacts with an app that includes a dropbox widget, they identify themselves and agree to share their files with that app. When they signout of the app they dont realise that they have inadvertently signed into Dropbox.com and are still signed in after they close the app. If you look at other providers, Facebook, Windows and LinkedIn i know to have already adopted this logout feature.

Comment: You could always redirect the user to https://www.dropbox.com/logout. Would that meet your needs?

Comment: Hi Smarx, thanks for your solution. I think the link provided by you could only be a possible solution to log out the user from DropBox in other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Call ah http request with your OAuth token

***XMLHttpRequest signOut(options, callback)***

[Refer Here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js) or

You should drop the tokens you got from the Oauth process , and start the login process over.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs#authentication-for-mobile-devices

Answer (score 1):

I use DropBox chooser, 
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser
Is there anyway to logout from dropbox on my application